# My website is returning 404 not found error

Tags: jsf-2, dns, tomcat6, http-error

My JSF website(http://discountbox.in) is returning 404 Not Found error since night most of the times. But my friends are able to see my website. When I access via my mobile I am able to access the site.

What can be the cause for this, of this. I have deployed the application in tomcat and not using apache at all. It was working for year, only since a day I am having this issue.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? Opens properly on my side

Comment: Ys I did. Its not working.

Comment: Have you tried a different web browser on the same machine? Did you try to ping its public ip address from the same machine? Proxy settings?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the DNS registered on your own router.

Your client (PC) in the same network as your server and aforementionned router needs to access your website via local IP (something like 192.168.X.X).